# how to use request attributes in JSF

Tags: jsp, jsf, jsf-2

I have added a attribute to the request in Filter. we are using JSF tags in jsp page.

I want to get the request attribute in the jsp, since i am using JSF tags scriplets are not working.

any one can help what is the tag to be used to get the request attributes directly in JSP page with JSF tags.  **I don't not want to set it in managed bean.**

filter code:
httpReq.setAttribute("xyz", "name");

this value i want to retrive in JSF page. please help sharing your ideas.

-Kiran

Answer (score 3):

It's just available in EL scope by the attribute name the usual way as `#{xyz}`.

Note that JSF stores request scoped managed beans under the covers also as request attributes!

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)